# Почему не работает запись звонков на Samsung Galaxy S8?

Tags: android

```
private fun getRecorder(absoluteOutFilePath: String, audioSource: Int): MediaRecorder {
        val mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(audioSource)
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(64000)
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(16000)
        audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL), 0)
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(absoluteOutFilePath)
        mediaRecorder.prepare()
        mediaRecorder.start()
        return mediaRecorder
    }
```

Так я пытаюсь записать разговор

```
val mediaRecorder = try {
                getRecorder(absoluteOutFilePath, MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL)
            }catch (e:Exception){
                Log.w("Can't start record with AS VOICE_CALL, try set AS MIC")
                getRecorder(absoluteOutFilePath, MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
            }
```

Все работает и exception не падает.
Но, когда записываю с SGS8 - используется `MIC`, т.к. при `VOICE_CALL` падает exception: `java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed`.

Я находил информацию о том что вроде как не для всех стран доступна запись звонков на устройствах samsung.
При этом, есть различные приложения в PlayGoogle (например это) которые прекрасно записывают разговор на этом устройстве. 
Объясните, как правильно осуществить запись звонком на данном устройстве и подобных ему, как обойти такое ограничение?

Comment: Такая же проблема с 8ркой, решил кто нибудь или может подсказать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вероятно и не заработает.

---

Android 9 Pie полностью запрещает запись телефонных разговоров

Свежая операционная система Android 9.0 Pie полностью блокируют запись телефонных разговоров, если телефон не взломан для получения root-прав. На это обратили внимание пользователи сообщества мобильных разработчиков XDA Developers.

Ранее Google уже предпринимала попытки бороться с записью телефонных разговоров, причём давольно давно. Уже с выпуском операционной системы Android Marshmallow в 2015 году, Google убила официальный API для записи звонков, оставив сторонних разработчиков с необходимостью придумывать собственные способы сделать это. Разработчики справились и альтернативное решение оказалось даже в чём-то лучше.

Теперь разработчики известных приложений для записи ACR и Call Recorder от BoldBeast подтвердили, что Google закрыла обходной путь, которые они использовали для записи, оставив только методы для рутованых смартфонов. Конечно, root-права можно и получить, но не каждый пользователь смартфона пойдёт на это.

Источник: https://www.ferra.ru/news/apps/android-pie-block-call-recording-apps-15-08-2018.htm